# Errores con xamarin y UI kit en visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, xamarin.forms

tengo problemas al utilizar UI kit Syncfusion en mi Visual Studio, descargué e instalé el kit y puedo acceder a las plantillas dentro del Visual, pero al momento de compilar me arroja los siguientes errores:

Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
Error       Failed to resolve assembly: 'Syncfusion.Core.XForms, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' Clean2  C:\Users\vampi\OneDrive\Escritorio\NEU\Clean2\Clean2\Clean2\Views\Login\SimpleEmailEntry.xaml   1

Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
Error   CS0234  El tipo o el nombre del espacio de nombres 'Controls' no existe en el espacio de nombres 'Clean2' (¿falta alguna referencia de ensamblado?) Clean2.Android  C:\Users\vampi\OneDrive\Escritorio\NEU\Clean2\Clean2\Clean2.Android\Renderers\BorderlessEntryRenderer.cs    6   Activo

He intentado actualizar, descargar de nuevo, pero nada. Cambié la página de inicio por la de la plantilla que escogí y sigue apareciendo el mismo error.
Si me pueden ayudar se los agradecería, he investigado mucho y soy novata en esto

Comment: podes mostrar el xaml donde lo estas llamando?

Comment: Hola Ramiro, gracias pero ya solucioné el problema, era la versión del Visual Studio, Yo tenía el 2017 y al parecer el UI Kit que utilicé es para Visual Studio 2019. Lo instalé, probé y funcionó!